# multidimensional array convert to date java

Tags: java, date, multidimensional-array, jtable, typeconverter

I have:

```
int lineTable = Table.getRowCount();
        int columnTable= Table.getColumnCount();
        Object[][] arrayTable = new Object[lineTable ][columnTable];
        for (int j = 0; j  < lineTable ; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i  < columnTable; i++) {
                arrayTable [j][i] = Table.getValueAt(j, i);
            }
        }
```

With this, I have a multidimensional array type Object with all data of the table... Can I convert this array to date(HH:mm)?

PS: The data is already in this format(HH:mm), but I don't know how take this directly in date format...

I did it! Just made these changes:

```
int lineTable = Table.getRowCount();
            int columnTable= Table.getColumnCount();
            Date[][] arrayTable = new Date[lineTable ][columnTable];
            for (int j = 0; j  < lineTable ; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i  < columnTable; i++) {
                    arrayTable [j][i] = (Date)Table.getValueAt(j, i);
                }
            }
```

Thanks for all!

Comment: Try `DateFormat` object...

Comment: Can you share the structure of your table?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); //your format here
        Date date = df.parse("11-3-1985");
        System.out.println("" + date);

    }
```

This will parse a date in the given format.  You can also create another DateFormat for formatting the date when you print if if you want a different format example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); //your format here
   DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
   Date date = df.parse("11-3-1985");
   System.out.println("" + df1.format(date));
}
```

This is just an example you can use whatever format you want...if you only want to give hours and seconds do that.

Comment: wouldn't this fail if the date format is MM-dd-yyyy and the date it is trying to pass is 11-3-1985?

Comment: @DarshanMehta no it will still work...it is smart enough to automatically convert it to 03.

Comment: Cool then :)
Also, I believe it is good to set the Lenient to false to avoid unnecessary rounding..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SimpleDateFormat` class to parse the `String` to `Date` object like this:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 String str = yourArray[x][x] + ":" + yourArray[x][x]
 Date date = sdf.parse(str);
```